# How to automatically associate a device with a device template?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

I want to automatically associate my device with its template. There is an article about this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#automatically-associate-with-a-device-template

the sample code for this is in JS and says to include `iotcModelId: '< this is the URN for the capability model>';`   OR   `'__iot:interfaces': {    CapabilityModelId: <this is the URN for the capability model> }`

I can see in the python device SDK documentation on keyword args available during client creation.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/wiki/key-word-arguments-during-client-creations

But I don't see anything in those keywords about the device template. I've tried a couple of permutations on my own, but nothing seems to work as I'm registering my device using `ProvisioningDeviceClient.create_from_x509_certificate`.

Anyone know the correct way to include the device template in the registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created your ProvisioningDeviceClient you need to set the provisioning_payload property to the JSON string that contains your model-id per documentation you have linked above.

Comment: Thank you!  "provisioning_payload" was the keyword I missing. I don't see it mentioned in those pages.   

Here are more specifics for the next person:  

`provisioning_device_client.provisioning_payload = {"modelId": "your_device_template_URN"}
`

The URN is the `Interface @id` which is found when you View Identity on the Template itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial and sample on Microsoft Docs that illustrates this using Python: [Tutorial: Create and connect a client application to your Azure IoT Central application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/tutorial-connect-device?pivots=programming-language-python).